# 3 Column (boxes) Layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to achieve this layout which is 3 columns with space between them, and each column has a heading and paragraph:
[image]

I've tried and this is the closest look:
[image]

How can I fix it? (especially the heading part)

This is the my html:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 5px;
  max-width: 960px;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.columns {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.column {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 10px;
  &:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  &:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}

h2 {
  padding: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thin;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e4e4e4
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <section class="columns">
    <div class="column">
      <h2>Cupcakes</h2>
      <p>----</p>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <h2>Join our team</h2>
      <p>-----
        <p>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <h2>About us</h2>
      <p>---</p>
    </div>

  </section>

</div>
```

Comment: The About column in the sample image is out of alignment and has a wider gutter than Cupcakes and Join Our Team. Is that intentional?

Comment: @JDB Yes they shouldn't be in the same size (what I've done)

Comment: @tom Please do not post people's code on jsfiddle without their permission. It is technically a violation of the the user's license and does not improve the post at all.

Comment: @JDB Next time ill make a code snippet of of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`margin` should be zero on the headers to avoid space between them and the container, but margin can then be applied to the `p` tags (and other content tags). `border` should only be  at the bottom of the headers to avoid doule borders. Other details see snippet below. BTW: Nested CSS will not work in the snippets here, you'd need LESS or SASS for that.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 5px;
  max-width: 960px;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.columns {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.column>p {
  padding: 10px;
}

.column:first-child {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.column:last-child {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.column {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 0px;
}

h2 {
  padding: 5px 0px 3px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <section class="columns">
    <div class="column">
      <h2>Cupcakes</h2>
      <p>----</p>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <h2>Join our team</h2>
      <p>-----
        <p>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <h2>About us</h2>
      <p>---</p>
    </div>

  </section>

</div>
```